# Capture keyboard shortcut and then enact another shortcut

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

For a third-party website that I don't control, there is a keyboard shortcut of command + K (on a Mac) to trigger some functionality (it opens up a command palette to search and perform actions). I would like to explore whether it is possible to create my own custom keyboard shortcut to also enact this command palette functionality. ie. if I press the keyboard character "." or letters "gg", to trigger the same functionality as native command + K of the website. I would execute the javascript using a Chrome browser extension when I load the particular website.

There seems to be many ways to capture a custom shortcut combination and then call subsequent code:

[Detect double Ctrl keypress in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707650/detect-double-ctrl-keypress-in-js)

But then the problem arises, is it possible to trigger a keyboard shortcut that is specific to that website (and not an OS shortcut etc.)?

This implies that calling a shortcut such as an OS shortcut would not be possible: [Javascript to trigger keyboard shortcut (CMD+SHIFT+4) on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70501439/javascript-to-trigger-keyboard-shortcut-cmdshift4-on-mac)

But is there an option to trigger a website-specific keyboard shortcut?